# sending and receiving notification in android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a service running, and would like to send a notification which contains buttons & also wants to capture action from that notification to run a specific task in the service itself.`RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);`

I have get a tutorial with remoteviews, but it cant help me for implementation..I cant find any way to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily display notification from anywhere. Just follow the tutorial here : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

The callback when a button is pressed is also explained there.